# Use of Scanners nextLine() throws NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

Im getting NoSuchElementException when running `nextLine()` two times on the same console while using `println` in between their runs.

First I run this:

```
  public void ask() {
    System.out.print(title);
    answer = getAnswer();
  }
  private String getAnswer() {
    System.out.println("Before first nextLine()");
    final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String input = in.nextLine();
    in.close();
    System.out.println("After first nextLine()");
    return input;
  }
```

Then I run this:

```
  @Override
  public void ask() {
    System.out.println(title);
    int index = 0;
    for (Option o : options)
      System.out.println(index++ + " : " + o.getTitle());
    System.out.println("Before second nextLine()");
    final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = in.nextLine();
    in.close();
    System.out.println("After second nextLine()");

    this.answer = options.get(Integer.parseInt(answer)).getTitle();
  }
```

Here is the output:

```
 How old are you?Before first nextLine()
32
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
After first nextLine()
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
Sex
    at SingleChoise.ask(SingleChoise.java:25)
0 : Male
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
1 : Female
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Before second nextLine()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Why is the exception thrown and how to I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing about the `Scanner` class is that calling [Scanner.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29) on the Scanner will also close the input stream it's reading from. In this case, that's closing `System.in`, which cannot be reopened once it has been closed.

If possible, you should declare your `Scanner` at class level, and leave it open. Classes reading from `System.in` generally need not be closed.

Answer (score 3):

You are closing the underlying stream, `System.in`, when you write:

```
final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
final String input = in.nextLine();
in.close();
```

You don't need to do that. Remove the `close` call. You might also consider using the same Scanner throughout (perhaps pass it around, or put it in a static field).

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc:

```
 * When searching, if no line terminator is found, then a large amount of
 * input will be cached. If no line at all can be found, a
 * NoSuchElementException will be thrown out.
```